# US holder of 10 year multiple entry tourist Indian visa denied reentry

Tags: visa

I've been living in India since 2010 and complying with the requirement to leave the country once every 180 days for years. I go to Nepal, spend the night and return to Dharamsala where I live. I just made this trip and was denied reentry, without any explanation on 9/27/2018. The immigration agent would only say that he is acting on orders from the Foreigner Registration Office in Delhi. I'm in Kathmandu, I've been to both the US and Indian embassies to make inquiries. The Consul at the US embassy said that he did not know of any official changes but said that he has recently heard of others like me (people who live in India on 10 year tourist visas) being denied reentry. Otherwise both embassies were entirely unhelpful.

My life is there, everything of value that I own is there, and two dogs as well.

Please don't respond with comments or answers that berate me for 'gaming' the tourist visa - India has been allowing this for decades, I know many people who've been here on tourist visas for way longer than me.  Otherwise, I'm in compliance with my visa requirements. If they want me to leave because they've decided not to tolerate this use of tourist visas then they ought to at least allow me to get back to India to reclaim my possessions and put my affairs in order.

What I'm looking for are useful suggestions about how to resolve this situation.

Comment: The presumption that you are actually in compliance of the visa, and you have the _right_ to get in again to sort your things out leaves little to answer - to resolve the situation, chances are you need to change your attitude towards the entire situation first. That aside, you are very likely in need of an immigration lawyer that specialise in such cases.

Comment: Wow, you really know nothing of my attitude but perhaps you would like to clarify on what you think my attitude should be. Indian Immigration has allowed this - no one is actually playing them - they know full well what's been going on and have allowed t for decades. I just want to get back there so I can get my stuff an leave in one piece. Otherwise I loose everything I own and have only the clothes in my bag and the shoes on my feet.

Comment: I totally sympathise the situation you are currently in. Though I also believe having a visa was never an entitlement, no matter how disruptive this might sound. I understand you might be desperate and are seeking an immediate solution, as any normal human being would, though to me you are risk making more mistakes and spending others' goodwill throughout the process, making the odds of achieving your ultimate goal getting slimmer.

Comment: In my opinion you will need to do two things now. Firstly, is to put the "I did nothing wrong, it is all someone else's fault" mindset aside - whether this is true or not is a matter afterwards, but assuming this will make your life increasingly harder as the incident progress. Secondly, you need to get the right help - ideally an immigration lawyer specialising in such case - and I can only wish you the best of luck here.

Comment: @B.Liu for a little context, Ubu English posted a [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/123213/19400) at [Travel.SE], and users there jumped on the supposed "gaming" of the system based on the fact that many (if not most) countries prohibit this sort of thing, without considering whether India is one of those countries. As you note, visitor visas generally are not an entitlement, but it is also rather unreasonable, even if entirely legal, to refuse entry to someone in these circumstances with no warning of a change in policy and no chance to settle affairs in India.

Comment: Were you registered at the foreigner registration office?

Comment: @phoog I read the post there (and refrained from commenting). While I don't want to further comment if what the OP did was correct, or whether what they encountered is reasonable or not, I see the last thing one should do when another party is taking the piss is to do the same themselves, which the OP risk getting there. Hence I was quite adamant that OP should change his mindset/attitude as the first step of solving anything - of course the delivery went all wrong and I apologise for that.

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, I do not intend to say "the OP is not in full compliance or do not have the right to enter". I intend to convey "_the thought of_ being in full compliance or having the right to enter" will get one nowhere. I will leave things here as I am unable to contribute anything else helpful to this case.

Comment: You should try another entry point. An acquaintance was denied once and tried to enter from another point and was able to do so no questions asked. Unless they "deported" you, cancelled your visa, or blacklisted you, they won't have information about your previous incident.

Comment: @Bat.Liu - You're absolutely right, and this is particularly true in India. But I'm not talking to them here. I did say 'otherwise' so I'm not sure where you're picking up a wrong attitude. I know how to present myself (with great humility, repentance and begging for forgiveness).

Comment: @phoog - At one time I was, more than five years ago, and even had a residency permit but they stopped taking registrations for people on tourist visas - I tried but they wouldn;t even consider it.

Comment: @UbuEnglish, it sounds like their attitude was already changing in regards to the use of this visa. Considering the relatively recent changes in administration of the government, this isn't too surprising and any others you know who are using this visa in this manner should probably take heed. Since your life is there, see if you can't use some of your connections to get you in touch with a good local immigration attorney and get your realistic options sorted out. There's not much better advice than that I think.